# uploading image to facebook page's album

Tags: python, facebook, python-3.x

I am new in coding. I am using this code:

```
import requests
url = "https://graph.facebook.com/me/photos?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN_HERE"
files = {'file': open('C:\\Users\\Leonardo\\Desktop\\black_background_texture_86812_1024x1024.jpg', 'rb')}
r = requests.post(url, files=files)
```

to upload an image from a pc's folder to the home of my facebook page. Now I want that the code uploads the image to a specific album and not to the page's home. In this way I can have all the images uploaded in the same album. What should I do? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick glance at the documentation (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/photo/#Creating) states that images can be uploaded to a specific album by posting to the `/{album_id}/photos` edge.

Assuming you've obtained the album ID, all you have to do is change the `url` variable to something like:

```
url = (
    "https://graph.facebook.com/{album_id}/"
    "photos?access_token={access_token}"
).format(
    album_id=MY_ALBUM_ID,
    access_token=MY_ACCESS_TOKEN
)
```

Comment: Thank you. Everything now is okay.